Coverted byte array to file but file not stored anywhere in phone device
Hi in the below code I am getting response in byte array .Now I am sending response and download and store into file .
But file not stored any where
val byteArrayRequest = ByteArrayRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,
    url,
    js,
    { response ->
        // Handle the byte array response here
        Log.d("volley","Response:${response}")
        writeBytesAsPdf(response)
    },
    { error ->
        Log.d("volley","Error:${error.message}")
    }
)

private fun writeBytesAsPdf(bytes : ByteArray) {
    val path = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    Log.d("volley","Path:${path}")
    var file = File.createTempFile("report",".pdf", path)
    var os = FileOutputStream(file);
    os.write(bytes);
    os.close();
}

file to be downlaoded in particular path

Where are you looking for it, and what name are you looking for?  createTempFile creates a random name beginning with "report" and ending in ".pdf". Make sure you're looking at the app specific downloads dir, not the general downloads directory as getExternalFilesDir does not give you a path to the global downloads directory, but to an app specific one.

@GabeSechan app specific one ?

report.pdf not stored any where

It wouldn't be report.pdf.  IT would be report<random_string_here>.pdf.  If you want it to be report.pdf, create the file with that name, don't use createTempFile.

And when you write to external storage like that, despite the name external storage, it does NOT get saved in the global downloads folder.  It gets saved in app specific storage on either a removable drive or on the emulated external storage of the device, but is locked to the app.  If you're looking in the global downloads folder it won't be there.

@GabeSechan can you explain me code where I did the wrong?

Using createTempFile is the wrong thing, almost certainly.
